# Updating Stripe PaymentIntent triggers no event and no webhook

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am updating an Stripe PaymentIntent like described in the docs:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update

I'm doing that localy running a Stripe CLI v18.

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_51KHpryAryfp4O0F5q2Kpy0QBlBNkMgFneHW4CqEH7eZrK3XPIGCnLJTRmXF9SA5z2ALwkLSUvU8WX91D1cEq5n0b00T9rU9q2u');
$stripe->paymentIntents->update(
  'pi_3KwR18Aryfp4O0F51SvBQWaD',
  ['metadata' => ['order_id' => '6735']]
);
```

Everything works and all other events that occur like `payment_intent.succeeded` or `payment_intent.amount_capturable_updated` are triggered and captured via webhooks.

Problem is no event seams to be triggering when doing an paymentIntents Update like shown above. Because of that no webhook can be triggered.

Update:
I also wanted to add I can see all PaymentIntent Updates in the Stripe Logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the Stripe docs that list possible event types, starting from https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.amount_capturable_updated and going down through the list of PaymentIntent-related events, there is no such thing as a `payment_intent.updated` event.

So there is no event or webhook for this and isn't supposed to be, at least with the current design of the Stripe API.

Comment: So when doing `paymentIntents->update` no event gets triggered and no webhook can be used?

Comment: Yes, that is true.